# Compile Tailwind CSS with imported custom SCSS components

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, tailwind-css

I've got a running Vue app created with Vue CLI 4 and also installed Tailwind CSS with the help of [this tutorial](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/setting-up-tailwind-css-with-vue/#using-tailwind-with-vue-cli). Since I want to put my custom components into single files and write them in SCSS, my tailwind config file looks like

```
// tailwind.scss
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@import '@/assets/scss/components/button.scss';
@tailwind utilities;
```

While serving the app with `vue-cli-service serve` or building it with `vue-cli-service build` works great, I am missing the autocompletion feature of my IntelliJ IDEA for all the tailwind classes so that I don't have to use (even tough great) cheat sheets like [this](https://nerdcave.com/tailwind-cheat-sheet).

My idea is to introduce a npm script that will build the full `tailwind.css`, so that the IDE can utilize it when autocompleting css classes. I know that I can manually build such file with `npx tailwindcss build tailwind.scss -o tailwind.css`.

However, although that gives me autocompletion for the built-in tailwind classes, it of course neither compiles the SCSS in my custom components nor does it resolve the `@import` at all. A solution could be to 1) resolve the `@import`, 2) compile the SCSS to CSS and 3) use the aforementioned `tailwindcss build` to finally build the full `tailwind.css`.

Since I am very inexperienced with Webpack, I wonder if you can give me some hints of how to achieve this. Would you even use Webpack for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is definitely the way to go here, I use this config all the time. See the Tailwind documentation page for [setup documentation with webpack](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#webpack)

Don't worry about autocomplete for Tailwind, you will learn those classes in no time plus their docs and search function on there are brilliant, no need for external cheatsheets imho.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `post-cssimport` you need to put the `@import` statement before everything else. Check out https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports